# Can VB.NET catch exceptions without defining a local exception variable?

Tags: vb.net, exception, c#-to-vb.net

In C# you can do this:

```
try
{
    // some code here
}
catch (MyCustomException)
{
    // exception code here
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // catches all other exceptions
}
```

Notice the `catch (Type)` instead of `catch (Type myVariable)`. Is this possible with VB.NET, or do you always have to declare a variable when you catch exception types, like so:

```
    Try
        ...
    Catch var As NullReferenceException
        ...
    Catch var As Exception
        ...
    End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotta be declared in vb.net. 
In fact when you type in `try` your ide should put in the exception type and format it.

like so:

```
Try
Catch e As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: And VB.NET doesn't give you the *The variable 'ex' is declared but never used* warning which you would get in C# if you declare it and don't use it.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio does that, which is what I was afraid of. I'll just put this on my "List of things that C# is better at." Thanks. :)

Comment: @SpikeX - VB.net is really wordy.

Comment: I use it because I have to, not because I want to. ;)

Comment: @SimenS Visual Studio gives me that warning for VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

In case a search engine brings anybody else here...

C# also has a syntax where you don't have to specify the type:

```cs
try { }
catch { }
```

I believe that will also catch unmanaged exceptions that do not derive from System.Exception. VB.NET can do the same:

```
Try
Catch
End Try
```